# Position of tags changes between different browers

Tags: css, xhtml

I am trying to make a template using CSS and XHTML.

right now the problem I am having is one of the tag on my template changes position depending on the browser. It is the way I want it when i open it with chrome, but when I open it with IE it shifts right....

here is the CSS code for my template

```
    <style type="text/css">
        #header {
            background-color: FEB7B7;
            height: 100px;
            width: 800px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            position: relative;
        }

        #menu {
            background-color: FBFEB7;
            height: 50px;
            width: 440px;
            left: 791px;
            top: 58px;
            color: Black;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            color: Black;
        }

        #content {
            background-color: B7CCFE;
            height: 730px;
            width: 800px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        #footer {
            background-color: BCFEB7;
            height: 40px;
            width: 800px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: make a http://jsfiddle.net for us please. (you define the hex color wrong, you forgot the `#` infront)

Comment: so the problem is that the menu isn't at the right place right? actually the menu should be inside the header because you cant say right is a fixed pixel size if the other div's is ware automatically in the center because it will depend on the browser window and screen size

Comment: basically if u open that with google chrome it's the way i want it, if u open it with IE it will look completely different. i think it's something to do with the way i did my position coding but i'm not exactly sure what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like micha said, it's because your menu is positioned absolutely from the side of the page, whereas the rest of your content is horizontally centered.

What you're really just seeing is the difference in the browser viewport size; try resizing the window, and you'll see what I mean. That can be fixed by placing the menu `div` INSIDE the header `div`. And then instead of using `left` and `top` in your `#menu` CSS, use `right: 0px` and `bottom: 0px`. That will anchor your menu to the bottom right of your header, which I think is what you were shooting for.

So your HTML will look like this:

```
    <div id="header">
        <br />Student Name:
        <br />Student Number:
        <br />Assignment #2: Introduction to PHP<br /><br />

        <div id="menu">    
                <br />
                <center>
                    <a href="index.php">Home</a> | 
                    <a href="Question1.php">Question 1</a> | 
                    <a href="Question2.php">Question 2</a> | 
                    <a href="Question3.php">Question 3</a> | 
                    <a href="Question4.php">Question 4</a>
                </center>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And your CSS will be changed to this:

```
    #menu {
        background-color: #FBFEB7;
        height: 50px;
        width: 440px;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        color: black;
    }
```

There are several other issues in your code, not to mention your coding style itself, but I'll just hold back on those for now, as this should answer the question you asked.

You can look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jblasco/qXSeM/show/).

Comment: thank you! ya i know the coding ain't perfect in the learning process =] ty vm for your help

Comment: hopefully u will check this again and if you do can you please just take out my name and student number from the code only because it's kind of personal and if you could do that i will greatly appreciate it

Comment: Oh, no problem, sorry about that. Just copy/pasted your code without really giving it a thought.

Comment: @jblasco look at [this](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fplaydoh.algonquincollege.com%2Fcourses%2Fcst8238%2Fkwok0016%2Fassignment2%2Findex.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) too!